# Regex capture all after equals sign and end before comma

Tags: regex

I have a string i want to separate but the problem is that as you can see below the strTitle param in my string contains a comma in the text 'sim, test'

how can i use a regex expression to capture the result and replace the comma with   `&sbquo;` ?

```
string strTest = "intWhole = 1, strTitle = sim, test, intClass = 3,";
```

Comment: Is the comma you want to replace always one string away from an = ?

Comment: What is the expected result? And what is the language?

Comment: Is there any chance of doing the replacement when the string is created?

Comment: aside from the initial instance (which can be caught separately) its always [comma_to_replace](^,)+?=

Answer (score 0):

Given your language/platform supports lookaheads you could try this:

Search for: `,(?!\s*$|\s*\S+\s*=)`

Replace with: `&sbquo;`

Would match any commas **not** followed by `zero or more white spaces and then end of line` or `zero or more white spaces, one or more non-whitespace characters, one or more white spaces and a = character`

So basically any commas not at the end of a declaration (since these are either followed by end of line or a new variable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. Every match should have two capturing groups - name and value. Basically it searches for string that is **at beginning** or **after a comma**, then a capturing group is getting you the **name**. Then the **equal sign** is matched. Then a capturing group is giving you **the value** that must be followed by **end of string** or **another value** (by a positive lookahead).

The key here is to ***not*** have equal sign in value.

```
(?:^|(?:, )([a-zA-Z]+)(?: = )(.+)(?=$|(?:, [a-zA-Z]+ = ))
```

Having the result, you can replace comma easily within the value (depending on language you are using). btw this above is java regular expression.